# Jenkins install windows 8

Tags: java, jenkins

I want to install Jenkins on my windows 8. So I downloaded the msi and installed it, but when I open localhost:8080 I get a connection error. When I try to start it via terminal I get this log:

```
Dez 01, 2013 7:36:18 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Extract jar:file:/D:/jenkins/jenkins.war!/ to C:\Windows\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jenkins.war--any-\webapp
Dez 01, 2013 7:36:25 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Dez 01, 2013 7:36:26 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
Dez 01, 2013 7:36:26 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled
Dez 01, 2013 7:36:26 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Dez 01, 2013 7:36:27 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Dez 01, 2013 7:36:27 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Dez 01, 2013 7:36:27 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Dez 01, 2013 7:36:27 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Dez 01, 2013 7:36:27 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
```

And my Java crashes.

Can anyone give me a hint how to fix this?

Comment: If you say: `Java crashes`, what exactly do you mean by that? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: The log doesn't contain any error message. What happens precisely when "your Java crashes". I'm sure you're getting a detailed error message or an exception stack trace. Read it, and post it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in new Version 1.542. See changelog http://jenkins-ci.org/changelog